# Add feedback form inside an ACF text zone in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, forms, feedback, advanced-custom-fields, twenty-ten-theme

I have a WordPress blog that let users (only for internal usage) write reports. There are "tasks" that they can select (checkboxes) to include in the report. Those that are selected pop a title and blank text zone on the bottom to include some informations. There is a task that is for feedback.

My question: I wanted to know if it is possible to replace the text zone with a form? Or add the form inside the text zone?

This is what the tasks list looks like, using the twentyten theme and ACF;
[image]
[image]

One of the tasks (checkboxes) is for feedback. I would like to have a complete form instead, with questions like "Did you see that?" with checkboxes, if they check "yes" then a text zone pop under it so people can write down feedback on that.

I cannot simply do a different type of page with a form and that's it, as the feedback is related to the tasks (to one specific report). It needs to be "inside" the report.

It seems impossible since one checkbox (for the tasks) only open one "thing" like a text zone. But I still hope there is something I can do.

Is there a way or it's impossible?

Thank you very much for all of your help.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is accomplished using conditional logic within the Advanced Custom Fields Plugin. Go to Custom Fields -> Edit the Group you want to change -> Edit the Field you want to be conditional -> Turn Conditional Logic on and add your conditions.